# How to solve ConnectException error when using Boilerpipe?

Tags: java, exception, connection, connectexception, boilerpipe

I want to use Boilerpipe to extract text from a newspage on several website, the problem is that every time I try it, I get a ConnectionException error.
I just used the example syntax from the [boilerpipe quickstart guide](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/wiki/QuickStart#Usage) :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/11523739/Nine-in-10-GPs-say-no-to-seven-day-opening.html");
String text = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

And here is the connection error :

```
de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
   at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:89)
   at extract.Test.main(Test.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I tried with a lot of sites but it comes to the same error.

How can I solve this problem, or at least see where is the problem ? (maybe a firewall, or port configurations...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further researchs, I found out that it was a firewall in the enterprise which blocked those requests.